# Minimize the distance to the farthest point

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

This question was asked in a job interview.

> Assume you're looking to move, and have a set of amenities that you
> want to have easy access to from your new home. You have found a
> neighborhood you like, each block of which has zero or more amenities.
> How would you pick the block to live in such that the farthest
> distance to any amenity in your list is minimized?
>
> For example, say your list contains {school, grocery}, and the blocks
> are as follows:
>
> 1: restaurant, grocery
>
> 2: movie theater
>
> 3: school
>
> 4:
>
> 5: school
>
> The ideal choice would be block 2, such that the distances to the
> grocery and the nearest school are 1 each. Living on block 1 or 3
> would make one of the distances zero, but the other one 2.

I came up with a naive solution as shown in the pseudocode below:

```
max = minus infinity
min = plus infinity    

for r in requirements:
  for i in blocks:
    for j in blocks:
      if j.amenities contains r:
        max = maximum {max, dist(i, j)}
    if max < min:
      live_at = i
```

If `n` is the number of blocks, the time complexity for this algorithm is `O(n^2)`, assuming the list of requirements is small compared to `n`. Can we do better?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11302600/839733) question seems similar, although the answer isn't clear to me. It refers to a paper, and starts with "Draw a circle at center, c", without any indication of what `c` is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it in O(n*k log n) where n is number of block and k is number of amenities

List of amenities  is small so create ArrayList 
for each amenity and store block positions where this amenity exists.

i.e. using example you provided:

- A["restaurant"] = {1}
- A["grocery"] = {1}
- A["movie theater"] = {2}
- A["school"] = {3,5}

So now we can loop throught all blocks and using lower_bound (binary search) 
find nearest block with required amenity for each of needed amenities

Then just choose a block that has minimum distance to required amenities.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the log n factor if you additionally store an index pointer for each amenity  list that points to the lowest index larger than the currently considered block. This pointer moves one step, when you encounter the index. This way you will only have to consider at most two elements of the list and you  can get rid of the search.

Comment: @SaiBot your suggestion is not at all clear. Would you like to post an answer showing how it applies to the given example?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a shortest subarray of blocks which contains every amenity. Notice that an amenity of the leftmost block must be present just once; ditto for the rightmost. The block to live in would be right in the middle.

A two pointers technique fits nicely.

Have an array of `k` counters, one per amenity in the current window, initialize it to all zeroes. Make two pointers, `left` and `right`, into the array of blocks; initially both point the beginning of the array. Then run the steps

- Ramp-up: advance the `right` pointer, counting the amenities it passes, until each amenity is encountered.
- Trim from the left: advance the `left` pointer, decrementing counters accordingly, for as long as neither counter reaches `0`. You have a tentative solution; record it.
- In the loop,

  - Advance `left` once, decrementing the relevant counters. Some of them turn to 0.
  - Trim from the left: keep advancing `left` for as long as no other counter turn to 0.
  - Advance `right` until all counters are filled again. It is another tentative solution, retain the best.
  - Keep looping until the right pointer cannot be advanced anymore.

Assuming that any given block doesn't have too many amenities, this will run in  `O(n) time, and`O(k)` space.

The proof of correctness left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Best approach is to Cache locations of required places and then find min distance accordingly.

For Example

# Time Complexity O(n + m), Memory Complexity (n + m)

def test(apart, requs):
    requs_cache = {i: [] for i in requs}
    for i in range(len(apart)):
        for j in requs_cache:
            if apart[i][j]:
                requs_cache[j].append(i)
    apart_min = {i: [] for i in range(len(apart))}
    res = []
    for i in apart_min:
        for k, v in requs_cache.items():
            min_val = 0
            if apart[i][k] == False:
                min_val = min([abs(i - j) for j in v])
                apart_min[i].append(min_val)
            else:
                apart_min[i].append(min_val)
        res.append(max(apart_min[i]))
    return requs_cache, apart_min, res, res.index(min(res))


# Output :- ({'gym': [1, 2], 'store': [4], 'school': [0, 2, 3, 4]}, {0: [1, 4, 0], 1: [0, 3, 1], 2: [0, 2, 0], 3: [1, 1, 0], 4: [2, 0, 0]}, [4, 3, 2, 1, 2], 3)

apart = [
    {"gym": False, "school": True, "store": False},
    {"gym": True, "school": False, "store": False}, 
    {"gym": True, "school": True, "store": False}, 
    {"gym": False, "school": True, "store": False},
    {"gym": False, "school": True, "store": True},
]


need = ["gym", "store", "school"]

print(test(apart, need))

Note:- If there are multiple homes with same distance then choose randomly.
```